# Including descriptive statistics in a shiny app

Tags: shiny, rstudio

How can I include descriptive statistics in a shiny app in r studio. I have the summary statistics in the app however I would like to go beyond that and add descriptive statistics such as the standard deviation, interquartile range, variation, coefficient of variation and confidence intervals.